# Cancel installing pending package with apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation, package-management

Yesterday I trying to install a package with `apt-get` but I regret of installing this package, but every time I want to install a new package the apt-get trying to install that package again !

How I can cancel hold packages in apt-get ?

Comment: What was the name of the package?

Comment: the package name is `oracle-java8-installer`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may not have removed the package correctly, or `apt-get` got interrupted while removing the package. First, I would suggest running the following to process pending operations:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Once this is done, use `autoremove` to make sure there is no garbage in the way:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Then, remove your package completely:

```
apt-get remove --purge [package name]
```

Comment: I had to manually removed all directories refering to the offending package in /var/lib/dpkg/info/, before your solution, to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I manually removed it from folder list. 
I checked the path where they are about to be installed.
On my part,

it's located in /etc/apt/souces.list.d/PACKAGE_NAME

I was trying to install spotify running Jessie from raspberry pi.
Then 'sudo apt-get update ' was successful again.