# Remove pending installs in Ubuntu Software Centre

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, software-center

How do I remove pending package installs from Ubuntu Software Centre? (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS)

I attempted to install a GStreamer package using the Ubuntu Software Centre some time ago and the installation failed. Since then I have had 2 pending package installs listed in the `Ubuntu Software Centre > Installed` tab which I cannot get rid of.

Periodically when I open Ubuntu Software Centre I am greeted by an error: `Unable to install "GStreamer Multimedia Codecs" as not supported` - see below. I always have an alert in the tab names - i.e. `Installed 2`, and in order to see the 2 pending packages I have to click the tick box in the top title bar (to the right) - see screenshots below.

#### Periodic error message

[image]

#### Before clicking on the tick

[image: 2 mysterious errors]

#### After clicking on the tick

[image: Once you click on the tickbox]

I have tried various `apt` and `apt-get` command-line updates/upgrades/purges as per [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885453/16-04-software-download-stuck-pending) and [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520378/cancel-installing-pending-package-with-apt-get/520380) with no luck, as well as uninstalling gstreamer [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638280/totally-remove-gstreamer-and-install-it-back-again) again with no luck.

Where can you see the list of pending packages which Ubuntu Software Centre is intending to install? Is there a queue or a config file or something separate to apt?

Comment: Does noone else have this problem? 6 months on and it still won't go away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the message went away after installing ubuntu-restricted-extras:

`sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`